# Rails 5 Devise Mailer inline attachments undefined method `url` for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I am receiving the error

```rb
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

when I am previewing my Devise mailers only. I am trying to add an inline image within my email.

```rb
# app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
   include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
   helper :application
   before_action :add_inline_attachment!

   def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
     super
   end

   #...

   private
   def add_inline_attachment!
     attachments.inline['logo.jpg'] = File.read('app/assets/images/logo.jpg')
   end
end
```

In my **mailer view**:

```rb
# app/views/user/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.jpg'].url %>
```

While setting up Devise I added the following configurations in order to have scoped views

```rb
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer = 'UserMailer'
config.scoped_views = true
```

The major part of my hair pulling is that this works with every mailer views including `devise_invitable`. It's the core Devise views `password_change`, `reset_password_instructions`, and `email_change`.

#### Things I have tried and failed:

```rb
# app/views/user/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.jpg'].try(:url) %>
```

That returns `nil is not a valid asset source`

I've also tried adding the attachment directly inside:

```rb
# app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
   include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
   helper :application

   #...

   def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
     attachments.inline['logo.jpg'] = File.read('app/assets/images/logo.jpg')
     super
   end

   #...

end
```

Also, adding the root for the image:

```rb
# Both
attachments.inline['logo.jpg'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.jpg")

# And
attachments.inline['logo.jpg'] = File.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/logo.jpg"))
```

Comment: what is the value of `attachments['logo.jpg']`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon with the mailers that it works, it shows up the entire bas64 code. With the devise mailers nothing shows up. So I guess, `nil`.

Comment: My bad..it is obviously nil, that's why the error, `attachments` is what i meant..you can do `.inspect` or use `p attachments` and see logs.

Comment: When I use `.inspect` my logs come back with `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/nil")`